# The sum of certain digits from an input number

Tags: java

I've been trying to sum a certain digit from a number, for example

```
Number: 5
Input:  54365
Output: The sum of 5's is 10
```

Second example:

```
Number: 5
Input:  5437555
Output: The sum of 5's is 20
```

I've managed to separate the digits yet I couldn't find the condition to sum 
a certain number (for instance number `5` like the examples).

I'd appreciate to hear your idea of doing it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    int number = MyConsole.readInt("Enter a number:");
    while (number > 0) {
        if (number % 10 == 8) {
            sum += 8;
        } else {
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of 8's is:" + sum);
 }
```

My way of separating the numbers.
Also i have a small program to get input instead of using scanner since we still haven't went through it in class.

Comment: All inputs are in *String* format?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide what you have tried so far so we could help you.

Comment: If you could provide some code, it would be great :)

Comment: You haven't posted any single line of your code, so we can't tell you how to fix/improve it.

Comment: Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get helped.

Comment: Guys I think the question was clear. OP said he already separated each digit.

Comment: Hello, i am new to programming in general, i am not so confident with my code therefore i opened a question without uploading my progress. i felt like its not getting anywhere near i need it to be.

Comment: I can say in general, My thinking went through Separating the digits, then using a loop to add 5 every time the digit is 5. But still could not code it. (The idea might have been totally wrong as well)

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka when you post a question, you can also include what's called "pseudo-code". What you just wrote can be translated in some way to pseudo-code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). You can even add your comment directly to the question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement seems reasonably clear to me.
Given a number

```
final int number = 5;
```

And a starting number

```
final int input = 54365;
```

The easiest way is to convert that number to a `String`

```
final int inputStr = String.valueOf(input);
```

Then, you can `filter` each char for it, and `sum` them

```
final int sum =
        inputStr.chars()                         // Get a Stream of ints, which represent the characters
                .map(Character::getNumericValue) // Convert a char to its numeric representation
                .filter(i -> i == number)        // Filter for the designated number
                .sum();                          // Sum all the filtered integers
```

Output: `10`

---

Using the same approach, but with an old-style `for` loop

```
final int input = 54365;
final int inputStr = String.valueOf(input);
final int number = 5;
int sum = 0;

for (final char c : inputStr.toCharArray()) {
    final int n = Character.getNumericValue(c);

    if (n == number) {
        sum += number;
    }
}
```

---

Your solution can work

```
int number = 5;
int input = 543655;
int sum = 0;

while (input > 0) {
    if (input % 10 == number) {
        sum += number;
    }

    input /= 10;
}
```

Comment: I am a rookie in computer programming, I was a bit ashamed to post my code here.

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka do this, post the code you tried. Don't worry about it. We all were rookies. So that we can remove that "put on hold" thing.

Comment: i was wondering if this could have been done by using while/for loops

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka see updated answer. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Is there a reason you're making all the variables final? Also , in the enhanced for loop specifically, how can `c` be final, considering it'll be constantly changing value?

Comment: unfortunately not, But i got an idea from your code to try something out.

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka is it because you don't want to convert to a String?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  int sum=0;
  int number = MyConsole.readInt("Enter a number:");
   
    
   while(number>0) {if(number%10==8)
    sum+=8;
   else {
    number/=10;
   }
    
   }
 
   System.out.println("The sum of 8's is:"+sum);
   
   
 
    
  }
  
 } its not working but i hope you get my idea